# GNOME 44.10: Drag-and-drop breaks Alt + Tab window switching in numerous ways

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, gnome, wayland

I am running a pretty fresh install of a [Bluefin](https://projectbluefin.io/)-based Fedora Silverblue atomic desktop with a GNOME shell using Wayland, and mostly Flatpak applications. (For what it's worth, I recently migrated my desktop from Windows to Linux, so while being semi-proficient on the Linux command line, I haven't yet learned all the intricacies of Linux desktops).

I have two very annoying problems when I try to switch windows using Alt+Tab while in a drag-and-drop operation:

1. **Problem #1: Skipped windows when using Alt+Tab while doing drag and drop:**
   When switching applications normally using Alt+Tab, everything works as expected.

   But when pressing Alt+Tab while in a drag-and-drop operation,
   the window that would normally be next in line (in the video below that would be
   Chrome) is skipped, and instead the second-next application
   (the text editor in the case of the video) receives focus instead.

   Based on my testing, this first problem seems to affect all applications,
   irrespective of whether they use Wayland or Xwayland.
2. **Problem #2: Tab key seemingly not released:** When tabbing into Chrome using Alt+Tab
   while in a drag-and-drop operation, it seems that Chrome does not receive
   the KeyUp event for the Tab key, and thus thinks that the Tab key is continuously
   being held down - even after aborting the drag-and-drop operation using Esc.

   It seems that this second issue is restricted to applications using Xwayland
   (like VS Code, or Chrome in the video below), while applications natively
   using Wayland (like the GNOME text editor in the video below) are not affected.

As a sidenote, the "drop indicators" (i.e. applications showing you a drop area while in a drag-and-drop operation) also seem to work only some of the time, but I can live with that.

Here is a video showing the problem (first just Alt+Tab, and then Alt+Tab while in a drag-and-drop operation):

[image: Drag-and-drop problem]

I have absolutely no idea what's causing these two problems,
and Google as well my own experiments haven't led me to any helpful results either
(I first suspected Flatpak to have to do something with the second problem,
but this does not seem to be the case).
Any pointers to what could cause these problems, or which components could be related, are very much appreciated at this point.

PS: For the sake of completeness, here are the versions of possibly relevant components:

```
Fedora Linux: 38.20240322.0 (Bluefin)
Kernel: Linux 6.7.9-100.fc38.x86_64
GNOME: 44.10
Mutter: 44.9

❯ rpm -qa | grep wayland
libwayland-client-1.22.0-1.fc38.x86_64
libwayland-server-1.22.0-1.fc38.x86_64
libwayland-cursor-1.22.0-1.fc38.x86_64
libwayland-egl-1.22.0-1.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-server-Xwayland-22.1.9-5.fc38.x86_64
qt5-qtwayland-5.15.12-2.fc38.x86_64
gnome-session-wayland-session-44.0-1.fc38.x86_64

❯ rpm -qa | grep mutter
mutter-common-44.9-1.fc38.noarch
mutter-44.9-1.fc38.x86_64

❯ rpm -qa | grep x11
libxkbcommon-x11-1.5.0-2.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-xauth-1.1.2-3.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-server-common-1.20.14-29.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-wacom-serial-support-1.2.0-1.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-libinput-1.3.0-1.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.14-29.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-xinit-1.4.0-17.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-server-Xwayland-22.1.9-5.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-fonts-ISO8859-1-100dpi-7.5-35.fc38.noarch
qt5-qtx11extras-5.15.12-1.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-amdgpu-23.0.0-1.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-ati-19.1.0-9.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-evdev-2.10.6-13.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-fbdev-0.5.0-12.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.99.917-55.20210115.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-nouveau-1.0.17-5.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-openchrome-0.6.400-5.20210215git5dbad06.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-qxl-0.1.6-1.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-vesa-2.5.0-5.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-vmware-13.4.0-1.fc38.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-wacom-1.2.0-1.fc38.x86_64
dbus-x11-1.14.10-1.fc38.x86_64
```